# ID Resistor value

Tags: identification

Working on a Ferguson 14M2 CRT TV (220V/50Hz). Dead.

Have identified at least one suspect in the hot zone. R88.
Have tried for hours to find a diagram online, but to no avail.

I believe it to be a 1.8 Ω resistor, but would appreciate a trained eye to have a look before I order. (Not a single shop in the entire capital of Norway that sells this over the counter :()

Here are some images:

[image: resistor soldered]

[image: resistor de-soldered]

Could it be a 1.9 Ω? And if so, what is the risk of inserting the wrong one?

```
1.8 Ω ± 5% => 1.790 - 1.890
1.9 Ω ± 5% => 1.805 - 1.995
```

Comment: more important is to find the cause of this current sensing R that overheated it like excessive horizontal frequency on extermal XVGA resolutions

Comment: or power surge or fast dropouts charging big caps  , one site says "TX86 TIPL791A+TEA2018A+R88(1R8) SCAN COIL PINS."  "TX89 DEAD R102 R88(1R8) R89 R91(82K) "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is/was very likely a 1.8 \$\Omega\$ resistor, as 1.8 is member of the common [E12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_number#E_series) series.
Also the second ring still looks gray (8), not white (9); although it could have changed it's color a little bit by overheating.

Without knowing more about the circuit there is no way to tell anything about the risk of using a (totally) wrong value. Although using a 1.9 \$\Omega\$ one (if you find one) instead of a 1.8 \$\Omega\$ with 5% tolerance obviously wouldn't be a problem.

What's more important is to make sure

- no other parts are damaged
- the problem that is the cause for overheating has been fixed.

Comment: It was all black of soot and dust when I opened it. (Entire interior.) After some careful cleaning I found it as is. Also did some measurements and found it to be kaput. Also found [this](http://english.electronica-pt.com/repair-tips?ref=TX89&marca=&sintoma=&page=2), though I'm not sure if the TX89 is the one I am looking at - they both (R102 & 88) are  in the same zone. The 102 is OK.

Comment: By "knowing more about the circuit" I meant to have at least a schematic diagram.

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned I have unfortunately not found any thus far ...

Comment: @user367890 It is a few-watt resistor, so perhaps you can combine a bunch of others to get to 1.8 ohm (series, parallel combinations). It died slowly, with smoke and stink. If it died fast, damage can be hard to spot, but still ends up "open". In stuff this old, check all the electrolytic capacitors too.